# Unable to connect with PPPOE

Tags: networking, 15.10, pppoe, ppp

Im using Ubuntu 15.10 and I have strange issue with PPPOE setup. I'm unable to use my internet connection after pppoeconf setup. I tried all possible solutions in the net - removed pppoe,pppoeconf and even ppp packages, installed them again. I even managed to mess up my WIFI access but after deleting resolv.conf and restoring  it everything came back to normal. After Plog command output was something like the following, plog says Im logged in but I still dont have any connectivity :

```
Remote message: ^M^JYou are already logged in - access denied^M^J^J
```

Im kinda new to Linux so any advice how to debug this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really newby mistake - as the message state you have to check for stuck pppd processes. I used  `ps aux|grep "pppd"` and killed the results. After that it was really simple and `pon dsl-provider` worked as expected.